# MSSQL - union all with different decimal precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, precision, union-all

When I execute this SQL

```
SELECT 1.4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2.0400 union all
SELECT 1.24
```

I get the following result:

*1.4000 

2.0400 

1.2400*

But when I execute the following SQL

```
SELECT sum(1.4) UNION ALL
SELECT sum(2.0400) union all
SELECT sum(1.24)
```

I get the following result:


*1.4 

2.0

1.2*

Why is there a difference in what precision (scale) is applied for all records?
Shouldn't it always use the precision where no data is loss, just like the 1st sql?

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is quite an old question, but none of the existing answers seem to address the "why?" aspect to your question.

First, what is the data type for your literal expressions? I wasn't sure (and didn't look it up) so I ran the following:

```
select 1.4 union all
select 'frob'
```

which returns the error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Okay, so `1.4` and the other literals are `numeric` - a.k.a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Next, what is the return type of the [`SUM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) function, if passed a `decimal(p,s)`<sup>1</sup>:

> **decimal(38, s)**

Okay, so the data types of the 3 `SUM` expressions in your query are `decimal(38,1)`, `decimal(38,4)` and `decimal(38,2)`. Given those 3 data types available to pick from, `decimal(38,1)` is the final chosen type, based on the rules for [differing precisions and scales](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx).

> The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

So, finally, back to the documentation on `decimal`:

> By default, SQL Server uses rounding when converting a number to a decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale. However, if the SET ARITHABORT option is ON, SQL Server raises an error when overflow occurs. Loss of only precision and scale is not sufficient to raise an error.

So that's your final result.

---

<sup>1</sup> At first this type may seem surprising, until you realise that generally, `sum` will operate against multiple rows and it's easily possible for multiple values of a given precision and scale to overflow their own data type. `decimal(38,s)` gives the largest possible space to accommodate any overflows without losing any precision, for a *particular* `SUM()` occurrence, and means that the final data type can be decided upon before the query has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for same result,

```
SELECT Cast(Sum(1.4) As Numeric(18,4)) UNION ALL
SELECT Cast(Sum(2.0400) As Numeric(18,4)) union all
SELECT Cast(Sum(1.24) As Numeric(18,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT sum(1.4)/1.0 UNION ALL
SELECT sum(2.0400)/1.0 union all
SELECT sum(1.24)/1.0
```

OR

```
SELECT sum(1.4)/1.0 UNION ALL
SELECT sum(2.0400) union all
SELECT sum(1.24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal Query passing String Value otherwise using sum or decimal it is string convert to specified format this is fact

```
SELECT sum(convert(decimal,1.4,3)) UNION ALL
SELECT sum(2.0400) union all
SELECT sum(1.24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT convert(decimal(18,4),Sum(1.4)) UNION ALL

SELECT convert(decimal(18,4),Sum(2.0400)) UNION ALL

SELECT convert(decimal(18,4),Sum(1.24))
```